# Failed to set unsafe attribute

Tags: php, yii

Hi i have warning string in log while insert and update action

```
2013/02/05 16:43:57 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "logo" of "Model".
```

Rules for model

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('typeId, cityId, new', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('title, url', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('content, created, deleted', 'safe'),

        array('url', 'url', 'on'=>'insert, update'),

        array('typeId, cityId, title', 'required', 'on'=>'insert, update'),

        array('logo', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'maxSize'=>100*1024, 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'tooLarge'=>'{attribute} is too large to be uploaded. Maximum size is 100kB.'),

        array('id, typeId, cityId, title, content, new, url, logo', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

I can't understand why I get this worning. I have rule for logo field and have allowEmpty option for it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[CFileValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator) is by default unsafe, from the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#safe-detail):

> safe property (available since v1.1.12) public boolean $safe;
>
> whether attributes listed with this validator should be considered
>   safe for massive assignment. For this validator it defaults to false.

So set safe attribute to true

```
array('logo', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png','safe'=>true, 'maxSize'=>100*1024, 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'tooLarge'=>'{attribute} is too large to be uploaded. Maximum size is 100kB.'),
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set [`safe`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#safe-detail) attribute of [`CFileValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator) to true

```
array('logo', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png','safe'=>true, 'maxSize'=>100*1024, 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'tooLarge'=>'{attribute} is too large to be uploaded. Maximum size is 100kB.'),
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Yii2**

Possible causes you get this error due to the form 'enctype' is not set properly for file uploads.

```
Failed to set unsafe attribute 'id' in
```

Enable the form multipart/form-data

```
// Form
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]);
```